# how to control the python xmlrpc client's port number under 1000?

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I used python xmlrpc to call the function on remote xmlrpc server.
Client end's port number is random from 1~65535, But the port is limited under 1000, Because of the IT policy.So,how to control the python xmlrpc client's port number under 1000?

Comment: It's not random, is it? The port is specified by the server: `server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))`.

Comment: The server is specified,

Comment: Assuming the port number being used is taken from the ephemeral pool, you can control which ports your OS allocates using steps similar to the ones [outlined here](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html#Changing).

Comment: But the client connect to server is random,client user the socket to connect server.

Comment: tcp        0      1 12.12.12.12:42222         192.168.1.136:8080          SYN_SENT    on (1.85/2/0)     . see the netstate. the 192.168.1.136 is the server  . 12.12.12.12 is local pc

Comment: As a follow up, I'm not sure any OS's allow you to set your ephemeral ports that low.

Comment: thx jed. it works on centos 6, but too risk ?  tcp        0      1 *.*.*.*:998           192.168.1.136:8080          SYN_SENT    on (2.77/2/0)

Comment: Its a bit risky because you're seriously confining the range that your programs can use to bind unassigned outgoing ports to.  So if you have a ton of processes, you can run out of ports.  It also clashes with the 0-1000 or 0-1024 range usually reserved for root processes.  You might consider changing the port range, running your program, then changing it back to default ranges -- or possibly change the ranges inside your script, then back again inside your script -- so that your changes don't affect most other processes